# Mongodb C driver, test if server is running?

Tags: mongo-c-driver

I've created a client that needs to read and process data from the database.

I've realised that I can't test the connection I create with mongoc_client_new by just testing if that is null, because the driver uses lazy connections.

How do I test if the database is actually up and running then? Maybe searching the database with no query criteria added?

I tried get_collection_count but that spits out -1 whether the database is running or not.

Answer (score 2):

I assume mongoc_client_get_server_status can give the info.

```
      bson_t reply;
      bson_error_t error;
      if(mongoc_client_get_server_status(client, nullptr, &reply, &error)) {
        bson_iter_t iter;
        assert(bson_iter_init_find (&iter, &reply, "ok"));
      }
      bson_destroy(&reply);
```